# I cant understand LSTM implementation in tensorflow 1

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have been looking at an implementation of LSTM layers in a neural network architecture. An LSTM layer has been defined in it as given below. I am having trouble understanding this code. I have listed my doubts after the code snippet.

code source:https://gist.github.com/awjuliani/66e8f477fc1ad000b1314809d8523455#file-a3c-py

```
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(RNN_SIZE,state_is_tuple=True)
    c_init = np.zeros((1, lstm_cell.state_size.c), np.float32)
    h_init = np.zeros((1, lstm_cell.state_size.h), np.float32)
    state_init = [c_init, h_init]
    c_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm_cell.state_size.c])
    h_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm_cell.state_size.h])
    state_in = (c_in, h_in)
    rnn_in = tf.expand_dims(self.h3, [0])
    step_size = tf.shape(inputs)[:1]
    state_in = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c_in, h_in)
    lstm_outputs, lstm_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    lstm_cell, rnn_in, initial_state=state_in, sequence_length=step_size,
    time_major=False)
    lstm_c, lstm_h = lstm_state
    state_out = (lstm_c[:1, :], lstm_h[:1, :])
    self.rnn_out = tf.reshape(lstm_outputs, [-1, RNN_SIZE])
```

Here are my doubts:

1. I understand we need to initialize a random Context and hidden
   vectors to pass to our first LSTM cell. But why do initialize both c_init, h_init and then c_in, h_in. What purpose do they serve?
   How are they different from each other? (same for state_in and state_init?)
2. Why do we use LSTMStateTuple?

Comment: Before going into details, Can you please let us know if you have taken this Code from an Authentic Source. If so, please specify the link of the source so that we can dive deep and can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport yes, the source is from a blog series. The git: https://gist.github.com/awjuliani/66e8f477fc1ad000b1314809d8523455#file-a3c-py

Comment: Sorry for an additional question instead of solution. Is that code working? Did you execute it?

Comment: @TensorflowSupport yes its taken from a working code file

Answer (score 0):

```
def work(self, max_episode_length, gamma, sess, coord, saver, dep):
........
rnn_state = self.local_AC.state_init

def train(self, rollout, sess, gamma, bootstrap_value):
......
rnn_state = self.local_AC.state_init
feed_dict = {self.local_AC.target_v: discounted_rewards,
                 self.local_AC.inputs: np.vstack(observations),
                 self.local_AC.actions: actions,
                 self.local_AC.advantages: advantages,
                 self.local_AC.state_in[0]: rnn_state[0],
                 self.local_AC.state_in[1]: rnn_state[1]}
```

At the beginning of work, and then
before training a new batch, the network state is filled with zeros

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I understand we need to initialize a random Context and hidden vectors to pass to our first LSTM cell. But why do initialize both c_init, h_init, and then c_in, h_in. What purpose do they serve? How are they different from each other? (same for state_in and state_init?)

To start using LSTM, one should initialise its cell and state state - named `c` and `h` respectively. For every input, these states are considered 'empty' and should be initialised with zeros. So that, we have  here

```py
c_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm_cell.state_size.c])
h_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm_cell.state_size.h])
state_in = (c_in, h_in)
state_in = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c_in, h_in)
```

Why are there are two variables, `state_in` and `state_init`? The first is just *placeholders* that will be initialised with the second at the evaluation state (i.e., session.run). Because `state_in` doesn't contain any actual values, in other words, numpy arrays are used during the training phase and `tf.placeholders` during the phase when one defines an architecture of the network.

**TL;DR**
Why so? Well, tf1.x (was?) is quite a low-level system. It has the following entities:

- `tf.Session` aka computational session - thing that contain a computational graph(s) and allows user to provide inputs to the graph(s) via `session.run`.
- `tf.Graph`, that is a representation of a computational graph. Usually engineer defines graph using `tf.placeholder`s and `tf.Variables`s. One could connect them 'just like' math operations:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1,))
  b = tf.Variable(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
  tf.global_variables_initializer()
  c = a * b
  # ...and so on
```

- tf. placeholder's are *placeholers*, but not actual values, intended to be filled with actual values at the `session.run` stage. And `tf.Variables`, well, for the actual weights of the neural network to be optimized. Why not plain NumPy arrays, but something else? It's because TensorFlow automatically adds each tensor and placeholder as an edge to the default computational graph (it's impossible to do the same with NumPy arrays); also, it allows to define an architecture and then initialize/train it with different inputs, which is good.

So, to do a computation (forward/backward propagation, etc.), one has to set placeholders and variables to some values. To do so, in a simple example, we could do the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  a = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
  b = tf.compat.v1.Variable(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
  init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
  c = a + b
  sess.run(init)
  
  a_value = 2.0
  result = sess.run([c], feed_dict={a: a_value})

print("value of [c]:", result)
```

(I use `tf.compat.v1` instead of just `tf` here because I work in tf2 environment; you could omit it)
Note two things: first, I create `init` operation. Because in tf1.x it is not enough to initialize a variable like `tf.Variable(1.0)`, but the user has to kinda 'notify' the framework about creating and running `init` operation.
Then I do a computation: I initialize an `a_value` variable and map it to the placeholder `a' in the` sess.run`method.`Session.run` requires a list of tensors to be calculated as a first argument and a mapping from placeholders necessary to compute target tensors to their actual values.

Back to your example: `state_in` is a placeholder and `state_init` contains values to be fed into this placeholder somewhere in the code.

It would look like this: `less.run(..., feed_dict={state_in: state_init, ...})`.

> 2. Why do we use LSTMStateTuple?

Addressing the second part of the question: it looks like TensorFlow developers implemented it for some performance optimization. From the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.7.0/keras/layers/legacy_rnn/rnn_cell_impl.py#L715):

```py
logging.warning(
  "%s: Using a concatenated state is slower and will soon be"
  "deprecated. Use state_is_tuple=True.", self)
```

and if `state_is_tuple=True`, state should be a StateTuple. But I'm not 100% sure about it - I don't remember how I used it. After all, `StateTuple` is just a `collections.namedtuple` with two named attributes, `c` and `h`.